# Issues with images being beside unordered list item

Tags: html, css, list

I want to create an unordered list with list items that have images and the bullets beside them.  If I create a background image as the way to achieve this the image is appearing behind the text.  If I set the image as a list-style-image, it's not lining up with the text and it's taking away the bullet that I want.  Here is my code for the list-style image and I was going to attach an image, but I don't have enough points yet since I'm new to achieve this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

```
.ul1
    {
        margin-left: 25px;

        list-style-image: url('Images/Air Icon copy.png');

    }

 <div>
   <ul id="Ul1">
     <li class="ul1">Clean air:  Our emissions are 250 percent lower.</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you post a working jsfiddle.net?

Comment: dont set it as image, set `none` as style for images, use background and use repeat none, give some good padding and use vertical align. Had the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used for the same problem you had:

```
list-style: none;
background: url('something.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
padding: 0 0 0 30px;
height: 30px;
```

Instead of using an image that wouldn't align properly i decided to use it as a background and just don't repeat it. Play around with the padding and height untill it fits how you want!

[Jsfiddle if you're interested](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Ktk/)

EDIT: Just read that you wanted to keep the bullet. Take away the `list-style: none` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another way to show the image and as well bullets.

```
.ul1
 { 
   left:12px;
 /* list-style-type:none;*/
 }
li{position:relative;}
li.ul1:before {
    content: "";
    content: url(http://lorempixel.com/20/20/);
    margin:10px 0;

}
```

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cacumovi/1/edit)**.